# find multiple matches of overlapping substrings

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to find multiple matches of overlapping strings, with word boundaries. Once a substring is found, it will not be considered for a future match, ie the next search will start after the end of that substring. For example, I require these matches for this string:

```
pattern: "ab ab"
string: "ab ab abxxxab ab ab"
         -----         -----
                    ^ ignore this, since it is not a word boundary
substr found: (0 4)
substr found: (14 18)
```

I have written the following code, but it finds only the first substring. The problem is that after rejecting the 2nd match (due to word boundary), it does not find the 3rd match, which would have been a legal substring.

The output I get is the following:

```
string is 0 18<ab ab abxxxab ab ab>
    match found:start=0 end=4
        substr found: (0 4)
string is 5 18<ab ab abxxxab ab ab>
    match found:start=0 end=4
    match found:start=11 end=15
```

(1) how to fix the problem in this regex, so that the 3rd match is also considered? (2) I am handling word boundary check with explicit C code, can this be done as part of the regex itself?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int find_substr(string str, regex pat, int start) {
        int last = str.length() - 1;
    printf("string is %d %d<%s>\n", start, last, str.c_str());
    for(auto it = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), pat);
            it != sregex_iterator(); ++it) {
        int idx = it->position();
        int end = idx+ it->length() - 1;
        printf("match found:start=%d end=%d\n", idx, end);
        if(idx<start) {
            continue; //ignore matches before the start index
        }
        if(idx>0) {
            if((str.at(idx-1)>='a' && str.at(idx-1)<='z') ||
                       (str.at(idx-1)>='A' && str.at(idx-1)<='Z')) {
                continue; // not a word boundary, ignore
            }
        }
        if(end<last) {
            if((str.at(end+1)>='a' && str.at(end+1)<='z') ||
                       (str.at(end+1)>='A' && str.at(end+1)<='Z')) {
                continue; // not a word boundary, ignore
            }
        }
        printf("substr found: (%d %d)\n", idx, end);
        return end+1;
    }
    return -1;
}
int main() {
    string str;
    regex pat;
    int next;
    str = "ab ab abxxxab ab ab";
    pat = "ab ab";
    next = find_substr(str, pat, 0);
    if(next>0 && next<str.length()) {
        find_substr(str, pat, next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? `\bab ab\b`.

https://regex101.com/r/DtjGrN/1

This might require Boost (?), since I don't know if the standard regex library in c++ supports `\b`.

Comment: No, this does not work. In the same code I just changed pat = "\bab ab\b". Not a single match found. I am looking for a solution without boost please.

Comment: Sorry, for the previous comment. It works. I changed pat to "\\bab ab\\b". It works without boost.